# Facebook Video in Apple News Component

Tags: apple-news

I am trying to embed a Facebook Video in an Apple News Article Body.

According to the documentation iframes are not supported so I am left with `EmbedWebVideo` and `Video` Components.

EmbedWebVideo seem to only support YoutTube and Vimeo so I am left with Video component.

I tried both, `EmbedWebVideo` and `Video` componet but no luck. Both do not work. The `Video` component displays the player but video does not load. This was tested locally on a macbook (using News Preview). When using the same `Video` component with a link to an example apple video `https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8` the component loads the video and is playable.

Are facebook videos supported at all? Do I need a specific link? I tried both, the short and long links that I can get from requesting embed video code.

Components and variations of link types I tried:

```
    {
        "role": "video",
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPageName%2Fvideos%video-number%2F"
    },
    {
        "role": "video",
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/PageName/videos/video-number/"
    },
    {
        "role": "embedWebVideo",
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPageName%2Fvideos%video-number%2F"
    },
    {
        "role": "embedWebVideo",
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/PageName/videos/video-number/"
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a Facebook video using the `FacebookPost` component, but you have to modify the structure of the URL to get it to pass validation. A structure of `https://www.facebook.com/{username}/posts/{video-id}` for the `url` should work (note it uses `/posts/` instead of `/videos/`.